# tabbedpanel - stay on current tab but change content of tab

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I have a tabbedpanel with two tabs, when the user clicks submit on the second tab I would like to stay on the current tab but change the content of a tab with a new jsp.

```
    <td width="100%"><s:tabbedpanel id="test">

        <s:div id="two" label="Search" theme="ajax"
            href="/Search.action">

        </s:div>

        <s:div id="three" label="Add" theme="ajax"
            href="/search.jsp">

        </s:div>

    </s:tabbedpanel>
```

So when the user clicks add within the add tab, user is then redirected to new called confirmation.jsp within the new tab.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be most straight forward to do this with jQuery and struts2-json-plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I am now creating ym tabs using jquery but im not sure how to link to a new page within the tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery will make your life easier, see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs
This example from that page switches to the third tab

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
```

Have a look at the page